# UIStatusBarAnimation style .slide not working in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller, uistatusbar

Following with the `UIViewController` worked until iOS 15. Status bar animated with the 'slide' method. Now it just fades away.

```
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()


override final var prefersStatusBarHidden : Bool {
    return false
}

override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return .slide
}
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Definitely seems like a change. Either they've deliberately gotten rid of slide or it's a bug. But please rewrite the question so that the code is runnable and actually does something.